# Weihnachtsfest begehen

Tags: grammar, verb, dialect, verb-usage, verb-choice

In welchem Teil Deutschlands benutzt man diesen Ausdruck? Ist dieser Ausdruck im Hochdeutschen falsch?

> Ich begehe nächste Woche das Weihnachtsfest mit meiner Familie in Wien.

Einige sagen, dass es falsch ist, `das Weihnachtsfest begehen` zu sagen, da dieser Ausdruck etwas Negatives bedeutet.
Im Englischen bedeutet das Verb "begehen" to commit. Ich frage mich, ob man dieses Verb im Sinne von »feiern« in einigen Gebieten in Deutschland verwendet.

Comment: Man begeht eine Straftat und feiert Weihnachten. (sowohl in Berlin als auch Stuttgart)

Comment: Jemand sagte, dass dieser Ausdruck falsch sei u er  aus Kiel kommt

Comment: Auch in Wien *begeht* man einen Mord oder ein anderes Verbrechen und *feiert* Geburtstag oder ein anderes Fest.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Kein Argument dafür, dass man Weihnachten nicht begehen und einen Mord nicht feiern kann.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Man kann ein Fest durchaus *begehen*. Der Ausdruck ist aber sehr "vornehm" und wird immer seltener verwendet. Für so etwas "normales" wie Weihnachten, das jedes Jahr stattfindet, würde ich ihn eher nicht verwenden - Von einem 50-Jährigen Betriebsjubiläum oder einen 100ten Geburtstag kann man aber durchaus hin und wieder in der Zeitung lesen, dass sie *feierlich begangen* wurden, und besonders gerne *begeht man einen Ritus* (und nein, soweit ich weiß, ist das in den meisten Fällen kein Verbrechen).

Neben seiner eigentlichen Bedeutung *ein Verbrechen begehen* hat das Wort eben auch noch die Bedeutung "gehoben feiern" oder gar "zelebrieren" (Ausser der Bedeutung von *to commit* hat das deutsche Wort im Englischen auch noch die Bedeutung *to celebrate*).

EDIT: Noch eine Ergänzung: Die beschriebene Bedeutung und Verwendung ist nicht auf eine bestimmte Region beschränkt.